# how can I map a network drive using wmi

Tags: c#, wmi, mapped-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mount Network Drive with WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508844/mount-network-drive-with-wmi)

I'm mapping a network drive using c#. I found code on [the code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90143/Mapping-Network-Drive-using-C) that works beautifully, but in the same application I've been using WMI to determine where an existing mapped drive is pointing, as well as creating shared folders. In the spirit of staying consistent, I was wondering if it's possible to create and remove mapped drives using WMI so that I can replace the code project class with a WMI implementation.

Thanks

Comment: I don't really see the benefit of doing this in WMI, considering that there's a standard way of doing it that works just fine. Maintenance programmers are far less likely to be confused if you do things the *expected* way than if you do it according to some arbitrary pursuit of idealized consistency.

Comment: Yes, everything is working fine. I was just wondering if I can do this with WMI so that I can have consistent code for all these tasks. I looked at the post you mentioned before posting my question but it didn't satisfy my needs/curiosity. I am happy to leave the code as it is since it works just fine and does what I want it to do. Thanks anyway

Comment: If the question has already been asked, it's standard practice not to re-ask it, even if it hasn't been answered yet. Please see the [FAQ] for more information.